# jQuery cloned element not updating target information

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to have an add product button to clone my file upload. this is my HTML

```html
<section class="transactionalFormRow">
 <input type="file" name="receipt[]"id="receipt">
 <label for="receipt"><span>UPLOAD SALES RECEIPT*</span></label>
</section>
<a href="#" id="addproduct">Add another Product</a>
```

I have jQuery to target file name and show inside label. It is working fine and on a cloned product, it updates text back to "UPLOAD SALES RECEIPT". However, when I select a new file, it always updates the file name of the original file input(#receipt).

```js
getReceiptInfo($('#receipt'));

$("#addproduct").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var newelement = $(this).prev(".transactionalFormRow").clone();
  var newID = Math.round(new Date().getTime() + (Math.random() * 100));
 var newfileinput = newelement.find(".file-input").attr("id", "receipt-"+newID);
  newfileinput.siblings("label").find("span").text("UPLOAD SALES RECEIPT*");

 getReceiptInfo($("#"+newfileinput.attr('id')));

 $(this).before(newelement);
})

function getReceiptInfo(element){
 var label  = element.siblings();

 element.change(function(e){
  var fileName = '';
   fileName = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();
  if( fileName )
    label.find( 'span' ).html(fileName);
   else
    label.innerHTML = labelVal; 
 })
}
```

Comment: Your clone is duplicating the ID. That's an no-no

Comment: but I have changed the input id to a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You have to copie the event as well here some doc https://api.jquery.com/clone/

```js
var defaultLabel = 'UPLOAD SALES RECEIPT*';

$('#prototype').on('change',setLabel);

$("#addproduct").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var newelement = $('#prototype').clone(true),
        newID = Math.round(new Date().getTime() + (Math.random() * 100));
    newelement.removeAttr("id");
    newelement.find('input').val('').attr("id", "receipt-"+newID);
    newelement.find('label').attr("for", "receipt-"+newID).find('span').html(defaultLabel);
 $(this).before(newelement);
});

function setLabel(e){
  var fileName = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();
  $(this).find( 'label span' ).html(fileName ? fileName : defaultLabel);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="prototype" class="transactionalFormRow">
 <input type="file" name="receipt[]" id="receipt">
 <label for="receipt"><span>UPLOAD SALES RECEIPT*</span></label>
</section>
<a href="#" id="addproduct">Add another Product</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally made it working by changing getReceiptInfo function and adding a new for attribute to label.

```js
function getReceiptInfo(element){
     $(".file-input").each(function(){
      $(this).change(function(e){
       var label  = $(this).next();
       var fileName = '';
     fileName = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();
    if( fileName )
     label.find( 'span' ).text(fileName);
    else
     label.text(labelVal); 
      })
     })
 }
```

And add this into $("#addproduct").click

```js
newelement.find(".file-input").next().attr("for", "receipt-"+newID);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is very simple and can be achieved with very few lines of code.

First :

- the need for `for` and a corresponding `id` can be avoided by placing your prototype `<input>` element inside its `<label>...</label>`.
- make sure the prototype input element actually has `class="file-input"`, otherwise nothing will work.

```
<label><input type="file" class="file-input" name="receipt[]" /><span>UPLOAD SALES RECEIPT*</span></label>
```

Now, by delegating the observation of `change` events to `document` (or some suitable closer container), the original prototype `file-input` element and any future clones can be given the required behaviour in one swift hit :

```
$("document").on('change', ".file-input", function(e) {
    $(this).closest((".transactionalFormRow"))
        .find('label span')
        .text(e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop() || labelVal);
});
```

With that delegation in place, the cloning process is really simple :

```
$("#addproduct").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prev(".transactionalFormRow")
        .clone().insertBefore(this)
        .find("label span").text('UPLOAD SALES RECEIPT*');
});
```